# What would cause a website/page to list out font-awesome icon file names?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Recently hired a designer to re-design my Wordpress website.  The designer is leveraging Font-Awesome.  I have customers that have reported that they see a list of names and if they scroll through the list, they eventually get to the page's content.

Not everyone receives the list and I personally cannot reproduce it.  I've performed cross browser testing and the pages render fine.

For most end users the pages render as intended.  The only static variable is the browser is Chrome.  The issue has been reported on Windows 10, iOS and OS XLion

I have included a pic of what is seen.

[image: rendered page with list]

The URL is http://endeavorperformance.com

Any suggestions or thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try it over https? Several font-awesome related resources get blocked as they are attempting to load over http. This is probably the problem.

Comment: Great question and suggestion.  Purchased a cert and made the needed configurations for https.  Issue resolved.  Thank you for taking the time to reply.